# Getting empty migration when II try and create a unique index in my rails project

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, migration, constraints, unique

I’m using Rails 4.2.3 with MySQL 5.5.37.  I want to create a unique constraint on my table, involving multiple columns, so I ran …

```
rails generate migration add_index :user_objects, [:day, :object, :user], :unique => true
```

However, this produces a file, db/migrate/20160203003708_add_index.rb, which had nothing in it …

```
class AddIndex < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
  end
end
```

So obviously nothing happens when I run “rake db:migrate”.  What I’m I doing wrong in my attempt to create a unique index across multiple columns and what’s the right way to do it on the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [migrations guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) and [migrations API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html) generating migrations from the command line only supports creating new tables and adding new columns. The table that needs to be created or column(s) added is determined from the name of the migration using the part after `_to_`. E.g. running a command like:

```
rails generate migration add_username_to_user_objects username:string:uniq
```

would generate a migration which adds a unique `username`column (even if it already exists) to the `user_objects` table. Now, even if the command supported adding indexes etc. the syntax would probably be so hard to remember and fragile (because of Bash etc) that many would prefer just writing the code into the file anyway :) :

```rb
# db/migrate/20160203003708_add_index.rb
def change
    add_index :user_objects, [:day, :object, :user], unique: true
end
```

---

A suggestion: The order of fields in a unique index affects performance and some other rules regarding SQL. E.g. if `user` is a FK to `users` table, putting it first would cover queries where you use `user` in a `WHERE`, `ORDER`, `GROUP BY` etc (e.g. `SELECT ... FROM user_objects WHERE user_id = ...`) without needing a separate index for it. But a more important factor is [cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_(SQL_statements)), which is basically "How unique is each of `day`, `object`, `user`in `user_objects`?" Put the most unique first.

Answer (score 0):

(I can't answer the Rails part of the question.)

From the mysql commandline prompt:

```
USE databasename;
ALTER TABLE user_objects ADD UNIQUE d_o_u (day, object, user);
quit
```